# I have a GridView and want to trigger Select command using Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView `gridview1`:

```
row 1
row 2
row 3
row 4
row 5
row 6
```

and I have a star label that gives me rating. The label only supports Javascript.

```
_dopostback method
```

I have a `<%#eval("sno")%>` and I want the value of `sno` of the current row whenever I click the the label with anchor tag.

I also tried Command Argument, but that's not working with Javascript.

```
protected void myfun(object sender,CommandEventArgs e)
     {
         string s = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
     } 

<input class="star star-4" id="star4" type="radio" name="star" runat="server"/>
<label class="star star-4" for="star4"  onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('myfun','<%#eval("sno")%>')"></label>
```

I need the value of `sno` whenever I click on a row. I have thousand of records and every record has its own unique `sno`, ever after that I to generate a table regarding this `sno` on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet (re: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/209416/Click-select-row-in-ASP-NET-GridView-or-HTML-Table) could be used to add row `onclick` event handlers that you can customize for your purpose (see `YourFunction(this)`):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender,
GridViewRowEventArgs e){
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){
// javascript function to call on row-click event, implementing your business logic
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:void YourFunction(this);");
} }
```

Alternatively, instead of adding onclick event handlers in every Table row (rendered by ASP.NET GridView control) you can capture and process its click event using the following javascript snippet:

```
// ** add table row click event 
function row_OnClick(tblId) {
    try {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tblId).rows;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var _row = rows[i];
            _row.onclick = function () {
                return function () {
                    // YOUR CODE HERE
                };
            }(_row);
        }
    }
        catch (err) { }
    }
```

where table id (`tblId`) passed to the function corresponds to ASP.NET GridView control. The usage is rather straightforward: for e.g. call this function from page body `onload` event. Practical implementation could be found in: http://infosoft.biz/bus.aspx (row is selected on click).

Hope this may help. Best regards,